# After removing linux Grub error

Tags: windows, grub, linux-kernel, dual-boot

I have a dual boot Windows & Linux system. I removed the Linux partition, but after that I am not able to go in to Windows XP. It is not booting. It gives me a GRUB error.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I uninstall Linux from a dual-boot machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/521381) over on SuperUser.

Comment: You've removed Linux but kept its bootloader... You need to switch to a Windows bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to repair your MBR.

1. Go to XP's recovery console using a bootable CD/pendrive.
2. Navigate to your OS drive. For instance `E:`
3. Run `fixmbr` and reboot.

This will remove GRUB and install the Windows MBR.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow, but what do you want to do? If you want to completely remove Linux (sadly), you're on the right path. You just have to boot into your XP CD and let the Windows setup take care of repartitioning and installation. Why do you need Grub?

If you want to use both, Grub is obviously not able to find the Linux kernel that you deleted. The easiest way is to set up your partitions with something like Gparted, reinstall XP first,  and THEN your Linux distro (with Grub)from an iso or network.

Comment: He should not reinstall windows, he probably only needs to do boot recovery to reinstall windows xp's bootloader.

Comment: Yes, he can reinstall from the Grub command line, but I don't see the point if he just wants to use Windows without another OS. Excuse me, I understood that he had deleted the partition on purpose.

Comment: You misunderstood me, The problem he faces is that there is no bootloader (Grub starts, but cannot find its files), but to get the windows bootloader in place of grub's, he does not need to reinstall windows, he just needs to reinstall windows xp bootloader over grub.

Comment: The XP bootloader can be installed without the rest of Windows?

Comment: I didn't realize that was even possible on Windows.. Sorry.

Comment: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/292614-how-to-get-back-your-windows-xp-bootloader/

Answer (score 0):

1.Enter in System Setup by pressing F2.

2.Select "File Browsrr Del Boot Option" &press Enter.

It will Show list of all partitions on hard Disk

3.Select Linux Partition You want to Delete & Hit Enter

4.Now save all  Settings by pressing F10.

Now your PC  will restart and Windows  will start normally.

[image: Setup Utility]

[image: File Browsrr Del Boot Option]